# "No Backend Error " while working with librosa

Tags: python, librosa

```
    file = open('data.csv', 'w', newline='')
with file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)
genres = 'blues classical country disco hiphop jazz metal pop reggae rock'.split()
for g in genres:
    for filename in os.listdir(f'./genres/{g}'):
        songname = f'./genres/{g}/{filename}'
        y, sr = librosa.load(songname, mono=True, duration=30)
        chroma_stft = librosa.feature.chroma_stft(y=y, sr=sr)
        rmse = librosa.feature.rmse(y=y)
        spec_cent = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=y, sr=sr)
        spec_bw = librosa.feature.spectral_bandwidth(y=y, sr=sr)
        rolloff = librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff(y=y, sr=sr)
        zcr = librosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(y)
        mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr)
        to_append = f'{filename} {np.mean(chroma_stft)} {np.mean(rmse)} {np.mean(spec_cent)} {np.mean(spec_bw)} {np.mean(rolloff)} {np.mean(zcr)}'    
        for e in mfcc:
            to_append += f' {np.mean(e)}'
        to_append += f' {g}'
        file = open('data.csv', 'a', newline='')
        with file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(to_append.split())
```

By excuting this code gives me no backend error. I have tried installing ffmpeg . But it was not solved and the error is as follows

```
NoBackendError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-0137cee5a3ad> in <module>
      7     for filename in os.listdir(f'./genres/{g}'):
      8         songname = f'./genres/{g}/{filename}'
----> 9         y, sr = librosa.load(songname, mono=True, duration=30)
     10         chroma_stft = librosa.feature.chroma_stft(y=y, sr=sr)
     11         rmse = librosa.feature.rmse(y=y)

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
    110 
    111     y = []
--> 112     with audioread.audio_open(os.path.realpath(path)) as input_file:
    113         sr_native = input_file.samplerate
    114         n_channels = input_file.channels

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py in audio_open(path, backends)
    114 
    115     # All backends failed!
--> 116     raise NoBackendError()

NoBackendError:
```

How to solve this error ? I have even tried installing ffmeg but the issue is not solved . Is there any additional packages to install ?

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/219#issuecomment-281811667?

Comment: No , still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same error too. Just for importing the audio files, you can use:

```
import scipy.io as sio

samplerate, data = sio.wavfile.read(location_of_file)
```

Then you can use librosa for feature extraction